# C# Regular expression to squeeze word where every character is separated by a space

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to transform words written like "H e l l o Everyone" to "Hello Everyone".

If it is words separated by spaces like "Hello everyone, how are you?", nothing should happen.

Basically all single characters should be squeezed to a make a word and we can consider if it is more than 2 characters only are following this pattern.

If it is like "a b cdef" - Nothing should happen
But "a b c def" -> "abc def"

I tried something like this "^\w(?:(\s)\w)*$" but it is matching with "Hello world" as well.

And also, I'm not sure on how to squeeze these single characters.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(\w)\s(?!\w{2})` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: When I tried in regex101 online editor, it says this: "? The preceding token is not quantifiable"

Comment: No idea what you mean. I suggested [the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/2UWvXV/1) to match any word char that is preceded with whitespace/start of string and is followed with a whitespace that is not followed with 2 word chars.

Comment: With Python/Php regex libraries it is working. If i select javascript it is throwing this error

Comment: But you tagged it as C# now and C# regex supports lookbehinds. Do not use regex101 to validate a .NET regex, use regexhero.net or regexstorm.net. Ultrapico Expresso is also great.

Comment: Sure. But "a d ads" becomes "ad ads". However "a ads" will remain "a ads". So, if it is > 1 it is squeezing but as per the question it should > 2 ??

Comment: So, `a d ads` should remain `a d ads`?

Comment: Yes. but "a d e ads" should become "ade ads".
So, >2 chars is the condition.

and, I tested it in a C# program and i see an error while parsing 

"parsing "(?< !\S)(\w)\s(?!\w{ 2})" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to match chunks of single word chars separated with single whitespaces and then removing the spaces inside within a match evaluator.

The regex is

```
(?<!\S)\w(?:\s\w){2,}(?!\S)
```

See its demo at [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5CS%29%5Cw%28%3F%3A%5Cs%5Cw%29%7B2%2C%7D%28%3F!%5CS%29&i=H%20e%20l%20l%20o%20Everyone%0D%0Aa%20b%20c%20def%0D%0Aa%20b%20c%20%20def%0D%0AHello%20world%0D%0Aa%20ads%0D%0Aa%20d%20ads%0D%0Aa%20d%20e%20ads). The `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` make sure these chunks are enclosed with whitespaces (or are at string start/end).

**Details**:

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind making sure there is a whitespace or start of string immediately before the current location
- `\w` - a word char (letter/digit/underscore, to match a *letter*, use `\p{L}` instead)
- `(?:\s\w){2,}` -  2 or more sequences of:

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `\w`  - a word char
- `(?!\S)` -  a negative lookahead making sure there is a whitespace or start of string immediately after the current location

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/7CfiGq):

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!\S)\w(?:\s\w){2,}(?!\S)", m => 
    new string(m.Value
        .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        .ToArray()));
```

Comment: Out of interest, why did you use a negative lookahead of "not whitespace" over a positive look ahead of whitespace?

Comment: @RichardSzalay: I understand most people will say it's "cryptic", but it is a very efficient way to avoid alternation with anchors. If I used a positive approach, I'd need `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?=\s|$)`. Alternation is already resource consuming and using it inside zero-width assertions is adding to the pattern complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a pure regex solution,

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=^\w|(\s\w)+)\s(?=(\w\s)+|\w$)", string.Empty);
```

replaces *a space with at least one space and letter pair on each side* with nothing (with a little extra to handle start/end of the string).